# My css and js files didn't load when i use the public folder Symfony 4

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, webpack, deployment

I'm working on a website with symfony 4. Now i want to deploy my website on Microsoft Azure plateforme. My folder is on wwwroot and i can go on it but my css and js didn't load. if you want to see go there : https://synergie-2i.azurewebsites.net/SynergieInformatique/public/index.php/

I use with symfony webpack encore for the CSS and JS files.

this is one of my error:
`2synergie-2i.azurewebsites.net/:8 GET https://synergie-2i.azurewebsites.net/build/vendors~app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

i just want to have my css and js on my website. 
what do I have to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you deployed the css and js files with success because i can access to app.css via this [link](https://synergie-2i.azurewebsites.net/SynergieInformatique/public//build/app.css).
In index.html, you need to replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">
```

By

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/build/app.css">
```

You can use asset function in the twig file like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: i used `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}` and i try with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">`but i didn't works

Comment: I found somethink if my variable App_ENV is in dev and i write this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/SynergieInformatique/public/build/app.css') }}">` it works but if i change the variable in Prod it didn't works. I have the same errors.